# Return Object from WebMethod (AJAX ASP.net)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I Have an object 'Person' in C#, and I want to return this object in WebMethod.

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static Person LoadPerson(string id)
    {
      return sdb1.Persons.Where(x =>x.PersonID.ToString().Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();   
    }
```

and in JS:

function LoadPerson(id) {

```
    PageMethods.LoadPerson(id,onSucess, onError);

    function onSucess(result) {
        alert();
    }

    function onError(result) {
        alert('Something wrong.');
    }

   }
```

How can I return this object? I want for example to alert onSucess the Person fullName. (there is Attribute field 'FullName')

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just return it.

When you add this Client in your front-end or another application, the webmethod object will contains your returning object.